# Database After Update Trigger From Inserted But Not Inserted? [SQL Server]

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to create a SQL Server trigger that when an update on table 1 happens in the val2 column, it takes that value and updates table2. I'm struggling to understand how to do this properly on something that sounds easy.

[Image of tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQnOl.png)

I believe my issue is trying to set a value that is not actually from inserted. (The only value getting updated is val2). I don't know how I can pair where to do the update other than grabbing the ID also on the updated row to compare to the place I want to update. Any help/advice on this would be greatly appreciated. Below is my current trigger that does not work.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Pull_ID on table1
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    @id_ = id from inserted
    @val2_ = val2 from inserted
    UPDATE table2
    SET val2 = @val2_
    FROM
    WHERE table2.id = @id_
END
```

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: added a tag, thanks

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is not the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once** and the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select from `Inserted`? It's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: @marc_s I see what you're saying. Do you have examples of something that works like this anywhere? I wanted to use the WHERE clause to try and pin it down but I'm not understanding how and struggling to find examples online.

Comment: See my response - should be helpful, hopefully

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your trigger so that it can handle multiple rows - always.

So you a proper **set-based** approach, not relying on the false assumption that you only get one row.

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Pull_ID on table1
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE table2
    SET val2 = i.val2
    FROM Inserted i
    WHERE table2.id = i.id
```

The `Inserted` pseudo table contains all the rows that have been updated - their *new* values after the `UPDATE`. Join that table with your `Table2` based on the primary key column (assuming that's the `Id`) and use a proper, set-based, multi-row capable single `UPDATE` statement - and you're done!